# Как добавить в handler проверку regexp

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, бот

Как добавить проверку по регулярному выражению в код? Мне нужно, чтобы в `state=registration_of_the_application.first_time_last` проверялось сообщение пользователя по регулярному выражению:

```
regexp=r"^с \d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} по \d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$"
шаблон с 21:30 24.11.2022 по 21:40 24.11.2022
```

```
await message.answer(text='Укажите время:\nНапример(с 21:30 24.11.2022 по 21:40 24.11.2022)', reply_markup=keyboard_staff_exit)
    await state.set_state(registration_of_the_application.first_time_last.state)
    
@dp.message_handler(state=registration_of_the_application.first_time_last)
async def first_time_last(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
 
    await state.update_data(first_time_last=message.text)
```

Если я пропишу в отдельном хендлере данную проверку, она работает, но как добавить её в состояние, и сделать проверку if else?

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/regexp_commands_filter_example.html

Comment: @oleksandrigo смотрел  этот пример , но не понял как реализовать у себя!

Comment: @oleksandrigo там вопрос уже перестроен по другому!